# Power at the terminals of a PLC fiber optic splitter

Tags: fiber, optics, optical

I have a 1xN PLC fiber optic splitter which works like this:
The optical power of the incoming signal is P; the power in each outgoing cable is P/N.

I want to use the splitter as a combiner. 
If the incoming power on each incoming fiber now is P, does this mean the outgoing cable will carry optical power P*N?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an answer I found at the web site of a fiber optics manufacturer

A common  question  we  receive  is  whether  a  50/50  beamsplitter  can  be  used  in  reverse,  to  combine  the
signals  from  two  sources,  thereby  combining  their  output  powers.  Unfortunately  beamsplitters  are  reciprocal  in  nature,  meaning  that  they
perform the same operation in both directions. Since the light from the input port on a polarization maintaining splitter will be split 50/50 into
the two output ports, light sent back along either one of those ports will also be split 50/50. In a one by two splitter the other 50 percent is
simply  lost  inside  the  coupler  housing.  In  order  to  combine  signals  with  low  losses  the  two  input  signals  must  somehow  be  different:  for
instance light of two different wavelengths or light of two different polarizations can be efficiently combined.

And also this:

Wavelength Division Multiplexers (WDMs), also known as wavelength combiners or splitters, are used to combine or separate signals. We offer 2-wavelength WDMs for visible/NIR or IR wavelengths, 3-wavelength WDMs, and polarization-maintaining WDMs. Infrared multiplexers are an ideal solution for combining pump and signal powers or for combining or separating telecom signals. Visible/NIR wavelength WDMs are commonly used for multi-color displays, sensors, and microscopy.